# About changes which are not reflected back in netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, netbeans-8

I have a java source code of a project developed on netbeans IDE-8.0 and edited its GUI on netbeans.
After this i switched to eclipse IDE (kepler) and modified several files to implement some logic.
After implementing this logic i want to change GUI again but at this time netbeans is not showing the GUI changes in design view (but code is updated as changed is eclipse) which are made using the same IDE (before implementing the logic in eclipse).
I have tried several options like

- cleaning and rebuilding.
- coping the modified source code to another work space.

  Also window builder in eclipse is not able to parse the GUI java file.

Any reply for any IDE will be appreciated.

Comment: The GUI code from the form editor is a combination of the form file and the generated code. Generally, the is auto generated when you can the form in the digit, but is generated from the contents of form file. This is one of the reasons not to modify the "protected" code blocks and not use the form editors in projects that are built in multiple editors

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did the same what u are expecting. Also i am not able to open it in design view in eclipse using window builder. It shows errors in parsing. Can I do something to modify it using eclipse.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...